# In what instances do we create new memory references in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reference, pass-by-reference

I've gotten into a bit of an issue with a reference vs value thing here
https://gist.github.com/MeeranB/238e085aac8a9abc53ad8a297b03671c
Basically I've selected a HTMLCollection, and converted it to an array using the Array.from method, however I am a bit confused as to how performing a for loop on this new array object has changed the original HTMLCollection, since using the Array.from method creates a new array entirely, and therefore I presume stores this new array at a different address in memory.

I expected that only the divsWithClassArray Object would change after my forEach loop, and not the divsWithClass HTMLCollection

Does anyone have an explanation for what's going on in the background here?

```
/* Assigns divsWithClass HTMLCollection object value to place 1 in 
memory */

const divsWithClass = document.getElementsByClassName("div-class");

//Assigns Array object to place 2 in memory

const divsWithClassArray = Array.from(divsWithClass);

divsWithClassArray.forEach(div => (div.style.color = "green"));

/* How does divsWithClassArray reference the same memory address as 
divsWithClass
if the array.from method creates a new array and we assign it to a new 
variable? */
```

Comment: @EugenSunic I have added a github gist to the question: https://gist.github.com/MeeranB/238e085aac8a9abc53ad8a297b03671c

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Apologies, added the javascript part of the code in

Comment: @EugenSunic but if I modify the array value properties, how does it affect the DOM itself if the HTMLCollection represents the DOM and not this new array object?

Comment: the objects in `divsWithClass` are the same objects in `divsWithClassArray`

Comment: @JaromandaX Is it not the case that the Array.from method creates a new Array object entirely, rather than modifies the original HTMLCollection object? 

I read that the Array.from method creates a new array, as mention here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: the Array is new, the content of each element in the array is not ... try this ... `const a = [ {x:1}]; const b = a.slice(); b[0].x=2; console.log(a[0].x)` (array.slice also returns a new array) - of course if the content of the array were primitives, then this would be different, but you have objects

Comment: but if the array is new, how does modifying this new array affect the DOM if we're not changing the HTMLCollection?

Comment: you are modifying the Elements (objects) - not the HTMLCollection (array-like object)

Comment: think of this ... `const a = document.getElementById('id'); const b = a;` b and a both refer to the same object ... what your code is essentially doing when creating the array is this, in a loop

Comment: @JaromandaX ohh, so the new array contains references to every element in the HTMLCollection, rather than copies of the elements, and this happens because the elements in the HTMLCollection object are objects themselves, therefore when I perform operations on the elements within the array it affects the elements within the HTMLCollection!

Comment: I've added an answer that may be more useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that in this case

```
const a = {x: 1};
const b = a;
```

both b and a refer to the same object `{x:1}` so changing `b.x` changes `a.x` - then think of your code as essentially being this

```
const divsWithClass = document.getElementsByClassName("div-class");
const divsWithClassArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < divsWithClass.length; i++) {
    divsWithClassArray.push(divsWithClass[i]);
    // or divsWithClassArray[i] = divsWithClass[i]
}
```

The above is one way we'd have to do things before `Array.from` existed in the old times (pre 2015?), and produces the identical result as

```
const divsWithClass = document.getElementsByClassName("div-class");
const divsWithClassArray = Array.from(divsWithClass);
```

Comment: So Array.from does not create a new reference but not a new instance. So even this looks as an interesting answer, doesn't completely answer the question

Comment: @CarmineTambascia - it does completely answer the question, it may not completely answer a question you haven't asked though, but since I don't know the question, I can only speculate if that's the case